# Center one item in Bootstrap Nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center a specific link in my Bootstrap Navigation.

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default user_info_bar" role="navigation">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <p class="navbar-text"><%= @user.screens.count %> Screenshots</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p class="navbar-text"><%= @user.points %> Points</p>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> <!-- This must be in the middle -->
      <li class="user_follow">
        <%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path %>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <p class="navbar-text"><%= @user.follow_count %> Following</p>
      </li>

      <li>
        <p class="navbar-text"><%= @user.followers.count %> Followers</p>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

http://bootply.com/107875

Right now I have 2 buttons on the left and on the right. I'm trying to center the "Follow"-button exactly in the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav centerContainer"> <!-- This must be in the middle -->
  <li class="user_follow">  
     <%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.centerContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

http://bootply.com/107882

Comment: Is there a live version of what you're trying to implement? It would be easier to try and use Chrome Developer Tools to try and solve your issue

Comment: I have tweaked my answer. This solution seems to work, and is responsive.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45847/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-mike-koch)

Answer (score 0):

Try this then:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    position: relative;
}        
.nav-middle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -34px; /* Half the width of your button
}
```

You'll have to add a class `nav-middle` to the middle `ul` and you'll need adjust the styles to remove the left border beside the button.

Comment: My Problem is that i wanter to center only that specific link.

Comment: This is a nasty workaround :), although it works it will break on firefox cause of the left: 50% (and it wont center exactly in responsive)... but thanks !

Comment: Haha it is a bit nasty, but it should work fine in Firefox. And using the negative margin in combination with left: 50% will work responsively. Not sure what else your options are but good luck!